# Using volley the right way within eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-volley

I'm working with eclipse mars on ubuntu 15.04.

I'm trying to do the tutorial about volley (https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) but I'm facing some difficulties.
As explained in this tutorial, I've cloned the volley repository, created an android projet for it, marqued it as a library. I can see that ./src/main/bin/volley.jar is generated, so at that point I would say that everything is good.

Next, I created an Application project and in Projet>Properties>Android I've added volley as a library.

If I well understand the tutorial and some other answers about similar questions I've read, this is the correct way to go.

Anyway, in my code if I try some "import com.android.volley;"  I always get the same "The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved".

The only way I can make it work is by adding the source code of volley into my project directly. Obviouly this is not the good solution.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Regards

EDIT1:

Thank for the comments but it appears to me that those information are a little bit out of date. If I refer to the git history, volley switched from Gradle to Maven 8 months ago, so it does not build with ant.
Any way, as I said in my question, the project is already building within eclipse so that I have a volley.jar. So I try what is suggested: copie the volley.jar into the libs folder on my project. I'm surprised it does not work :/ Looking closely to the jar file I'm surprised it weighs only 166 bytes!

Referring to https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html:

> **Creating the manifest file**: A library project's manifest file
>   must declare all of the shared components that it includes, just as
>   would a standard Android application

and

> **Declaring library components in the manifest file**: In the manifest file of the application project, you must add declarations of all components that the application will use that are imported from a library project. For example, you must declare any `<activity>`, `<service>`, `<receiver>`, `<provider>`, and so on, as well as `<permission>`, `<uses-library>`, and similar elements.
>
> Declarations should reference the library components by their fully-qualified package names, where appropriate.

May it happen that the default manifest file from volley is incorrect and it does not "export" anything which makes the jar file being so small?
Does it mean that I have to put in both manifests (the one from volley and the one of my app) any `import` I did in my code?

Comment: Please refer this tutorials it may be helpful : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/  and  this for implementation : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: You can extract the the volley jar from the project available in the below link. http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: sanatshukla and darwin thank you for your comments, please have a look at my EDIT.